# get text from file between quotes and commas

Tags: regex

I have large file with lines like this- its one line:

```
('serve1','type',0,'zone.x.target',1,'ab23423u',0,),('actual','type8',0,'code.is.avail',1,'srerwerwer');
```

I would like to extract only text between ('  and ','
so in that example right output must be

> serve1
>
> actual

Comment: What is your language? Can you explain where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use look-behind and look-ahead positive assertion if it's available in the regex implementation you use:

```
(?<=\(').*?(?=')
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QSLmHoNq_9dVzk30)

Answer (score 0):

if your regex engine supports look-behind:

```
(?<=\(')[^']*
```

if you have gnu-grep available: `grep -Po "\('\K[^']*" file`

```
kent$  echo "('serve1','type',0,'zone.x.target',1,'ab23423u',0,),('actual','type8',0,'code.is.avail',1,'srerwerwer');"|grep -Po "\('\K[^']*"
serve1
actual
```